# ASP.Net ListBox inside user control not showing data

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have a ListBox which is inside an Update Panel, inside a user control.
I am calling this user control from another user control on Button click.
On debugging, I can see that the ListBox.Items.Count > 0, however, the listbox shows empty when the user control is displayed.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show me your code , Please !

Comment: Remember, by default, user controls won't keep their state. You have to build/rebuild them one very postback, or specifically keep their state using sessionstate.